# How to execute click function before the blur function

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-events

I've got a simple issue but I can't seem to figure out any solution.

Basically I've got an input that toggles a dropdown when focused, and when it's not focused anymore it should close the dropdown.

However, the problem is that if you click on an item in the dropdown, the `blur` function is executed before the `click` function of the item, causing the `click` function not to run at all since the dropdown closes before the click is registered.

How can I solve this?

```
<input onFocus="showDropdown()" onBlur="hideDropdown()">
<ul>
  <li onClick="myClickFunc()">item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Replace your click **event** with (*mousedown*). Mousedown event is called **before** blur. This code should works properly:

```
<input (focus)="showDropdown()" (blur)="myBlurFunc()">
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of dropdown" (mousedown)="myClickFunc()">{{item.label}}</li>
</ul>
```

It looks like click event has **lower priority** than blur, so it is predictible behaviour that blur event fires first.

Comment: This is has been something that has been an issue for me for awhile. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: but their is catch to it , if we do a right click it will also take effect

Comment: This is an easy fix, but it comes with a bunch of weird edge cases. There's a better option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57983847/202875

Comment: @AkhilRJ You can see which button was pressed using `MouseEvent.button` to disregard the event in that case.

Comment: Is there any source about the event priority?

Answer (score 36):

Make the options in your dropdown elements that can receive focus - use `<a>` or `<button>` or set `tabindex="-1"`. Then, in your `onBlur` handler, check [`event.relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget). In an `onBlur` handler, `relatedTarget` is the element receiving focus (if there is one). If it is one of the options in your dropdown, then you know not to hide the options at this point.

This is preferable over switching from `onClick` to `onMouseDown`, because an actual click doesn't always immediately follow a mouseDown. If you mousedown, move the cursor off, then mouseup, you'll trigger a mousedown without triggering a click at all.

```js
const elToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
const elMenu = document.querySelector('.menu');
elToggle.onfocus = (event) => {
  elMenu.classList.add('open');
};
elToggle.onblur = (event) => {
  const didClickMenu = elMenu.contains(event.relatedTarget);
  if (!didClickMenu) {
    elMenu.classList.remove('open');
  }
};
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
}
.menu.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="toggle">menu</button>
<ul class="menu">
  <li tabIndex="-1" onClick="console.log('tacos')">tacos</li>
  <li tabIndex="-1" onClick="console.log('burgers')">burgers</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's not necessarily possible to change the options to focusable elements.

Comment: in case it wasn't clear: adding `tabindex="-1"` **will ensure** that your element appear in `relatedTarget`, not matter what element it is. so this is should be the preferred answer in any way as it does not alter the click behavior.

Comment: For further context adding `tabindex="-1"` makes any element focusable. If the focus target is already focusable (e.g. an `input` then it's not needed). The negative value prevents keyboard navigation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: Isn't it better to use tabindex="0" in order to not remove the keyboard navigation?

Comment: @EranOr dropdown items shouldn't be navigable by using the alt key, arrow keys should be used instead, hence using tabIndex="-1" is fine.

Comment: I was looking for a solution that didn't mess with the onClick behavior and this exactly what it is, i don't know if it's the best way to do it but better than switching onClick for onMouseDown, definitely.

Comment: @Abraham Arreola, what about Tab key?

Comment: @EranOr sorry, all this time i've been talking about the Tab Key not the Alt one, i confused them lol

Answer (score 10):

Here's another way to solve this, and it requires no JS:

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
}
.toggle:focus + .menu,
.toggle + .menu:active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="toggle">menu</button>
<ul class="menu">
  <li onClick="console.log('tacos')">tacos</li>
  <li onClick="console.log('burgers')">burgers</li>
</ul>
```

The secret is to target not only the `.toggle:focus` state, but also the `.menu:active` state.

Comment: this answer seems the simplest to me. in my case, i used it for an autocomplete suggestion box, which i have a border around, and that border shows up even on an empty box, so i added `:not(:empty)`. like this: `.toggle:focus + .menu:not(:empty),`. thanks for this!