# Angular 4 (mousedown)="clicked" event not firing on a button.

Tags: angular

I have a button on my webpage that reads the value of an input and submits it to refresh the data on my page. it works in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, but it doesn't work in either safari or IE11. I tried adding polyfills to no avail and I followed the example here:([How to execute click function before the blur function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439115/how-to-execute-click-function-before-the-blur-function)) with no luck either. Here's the code for the button:

```
THIS.Name:<input #name /><button class="btn-standard-ico" type="submit" (mousedown)="clicked(this.name.value)"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Submit</button>
```

("clicked()" just displays an alert so I can test the button click)

Can someone point me in a direction so I can figure out why it isn't working?

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://embed.plnkr.co/43DoaVSLoZhtCYONkqpl/ Could you provide more of your code, possibly the clicked function? Also, is it possible that you have a class variable already titled "name?"

Comment: Here's my "clicked" method. If it was an issue with a variable wouldn't that keep things from working chrome and firefox and not just IE11 and Safari? `code  clicked(value) {
       alert("clicked! passed value = " + value);
      this.employerService.getEmployerAPI(value).subscribe(res => this.employer = res);`
  }

Comment: Also, why do you have this line in plunkr? `import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';`

Comment: That and various other unnecessary lines are in the Plunkr because I edited a pre-made Angular Plunkr template. I'm not sure about the problems between browsers. Will keep looking...

Comment: instead of `(mousedown)`, why don't you just do `(click)`?

Comment: that was recommended by the link in my original comment.